# Transferring terabytes of data between two machines efficiently (samba and NFS mounts)

Tags: samba, rsync, nfs, transfer, mirrors

I need to transfer `15 TB` of data from one machine to another machine and having failed several times during the past three weeks, I am out of options and do not know what to do.

There are two machines:

- source machine: uses samba share mount point and is heavily restricted (connecting to the machine outside of the network requires VPN and I cannot mount the share normally on the second [target] machine without setting up the VPN which disconnects automatically every 10 hours). My 15TB of data is on this machine
- target machine: which uses NFS

First thing I tried was connecting to the first machine and using a simple rsync:

`rsync -rvz --stats --progress /mnt/samba/my_15TB_data user@second_machine:/mnt/NFS/backup`

This failed after a couple of hours:

```
 rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

  12820840448  55%    9.02MB/s    0:18:31
 12820840448: command not found
 rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)

rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (731 bytes received so far) [sender]
syntax error near unexpected token `('
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I don't really understand what this error means, but from what I have gathered online from several forums, it looks like a bug that rsync produces when there's a huge amount of data being copied! Another possibility is that the connection between the two machines might had been broken.

I then tried to compress my data as much as possible, so I chose the highest level compression on 7z:

`7z a 15T_data_compressed.7z /mnt/samba/my_15TB_data -mx9`

This was going on all too well, but after 460 hours of CPU time spent on the 7zip process, the process was force-terminated by the admin of the machine.. I realized I was using all available cores on the machine, so admin had all right to do that after such heavy usage of the resources for only compressing files.

**What can I do to efficiently transfer my data?** More specifically, I am looking for a way that would give me the **possibility to RESUME the transfer** in case something goes wrong. For example, in the case above with rsync, I can see that a good amount of data had been transfered.

Is it a better idea to mount the samba share using the VPN (which automatically disconnects every 10 hours) and in some way mirror the folder onto the NFS? Is such a thing possible and will it be faster?

By the way, average transfer speed between the two machines is 12 MB/s. These are two different machines located in two different countries.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the *error* in rsync you quote seems to be that you pasted stuff into a terminal. It's not the original error message.

The original message, that you pasted into the terminal indicates that the connection was closed for some reason, like reboot, network problem or similar. But rsync should be able to resume.

Simply run

```
rsync -rvz --stats --progress /mnt/samba/my_15TB_data user@second_machine:/mnt/NFS/backup
```

once more, and it will check up on the status of the files, comparing time stamp and size, and ignores any file that have identical size and time stamp on source and destination side. This process will take some time, but unless it's a lot of very small files it will be quicker than re-transferring the files.

You can in general resume as many times as you want with rsync; it is a fairly robust file transfer mechanism.

Comment: Great. I will try that. Does the compression add to the burden of the transfer? i.e. does it take more time to transfer when `-z` is used? My files are mixed, I have a huge amount of extremely small files, but also a huge amount of 50 MB files and so on!

Comment: Compression adds some CPU load. Unless you have a fairly fast network link (>100Mb) this will be negligible. Also note that compression makes no sense if the content is already compressed, but generally will not hurt.